# cordovaActivity.appView DownloadListener err

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

appView is cordovaActivity.appVeiw 
DownloadListener is webkit.DownloadListener
I am also using Crosswalk in scenario.

```
DownloadListener dl = new DownloadListener() {          
  public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
  String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
  long contentLength) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
  }
};
appView.setDownloadListener(dl);
```

it give err while compile

```
sample.java:###:  error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         appView.setDownloadListener(dl);
[javac]                     ^
[javac]   symbol:   method setDownloadListener(DownloadListener)
[javac]   location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 1 error
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
appView.setDownloadListener( new DownloadListener() {          
  public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
  String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
  long contentLength) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
  }
}
);
```

Comment: same err .Looks CordovaWebView does not have setDownloadListner

Answer (score 0):

This code works in cordova 6+

```
SystemWebView wv = (SystemWebView) appView.getView();
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                 String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                 long contentLength) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});
```